# How to set locale for parsing in moment.js?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Unfortunately, I didn't find the answer in the documentation, so...

For example, I have input date: "09/01/2017". I don't know, it is DD/MM/YYYY or MM/DD/YYYY, but I know user locale. Can I get something like below?

```
let date   = "09/01/2017",
    locale = "en_US",// or "en_AU"
    result = moment(date, locale).format("DD MMM YYYY");
// 01 Sep 2017
// 09 Jan 2017
```

Or do I need to write a map and than set a format to moment?

```
let map =
    {
        en_US: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
        en_AU: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
        // ...
    },
    date   = "09/01/2017",
    locale = "en_US",// or "en_AU"
    result = moment(date, map[locale]).format("DD MMM YYYY");
// 01 Sep 2017
// 09 Jan 2017
```

Thanks

Comment: [Moment.js - i18n](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/)

Comment: "*…but I know user locale*". Where a user is located is not a reliable indicator of the date format they might use.

Comment: "en–AU" is not a locale, it's a language tag. It does not relate in any way to where a person is (i.e. their locale). I really can't understand how this misnomer (that seems to have emanated from ECMA-402) persists or why otherwise intelligent people propagate it.

Comment: In the context of my task, this tag indicates the format of the data, so it's ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`moment.localeData()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/locale-data/) and `longDateFormat('L')` do get locale specific tokens.

Here a live sample:

```js
let date   = "09/01/2017";
let locale = "en_US";
let localeFormat =  moment.localeData(locale).longDateFormat('L');
let result = moment(date, localeFormat).format("DD MMM YYYY");
console.log(result); // 01 Sep 2017

locale = "en_AU";
localeFormat =  moment.localeData(locale).longDateFormat('L');
result = moment(date, localeFormat).format("DD MMM YYYY");
console.log(result); // 09 Jan 2017
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use plain JS to pull the month based on local, use moment to format the month to  MMM, then just join em up.

```
var locale = 'en_AU'

var date = '09/01/2019'.split('/')

if (locale === 'en_AU') {
    var monthFormatted = moment(date[0]).format('MMM')
    date = [date[1], monthFormatted, date[2]].join(' ')
}

else {
    var monthFormatted = moment(date[1]).format('MMM')
    date = [date[0], monthFormatted, date[2]].join(' ')
}

console.log(date)
// 09 Jan 2019 or 01 Sep 2019
```